# How to reset console colors in nodejs within VSCode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

My application writes in different colors to the console using `console.log`. When it terminates, the command line prompt should return to it's previous color and not, say, green.

I tried to achieve this by resetting the color on the last line of my code with `console.log("\x1b[0m")`...

```
console.log("\x1b[32m", "SUCCESS: pow.js passed successfully")
console.log("\x1b[0m")
process.exit(0)
```

...with mixed results - in a normal terminal it works:

[image]

In VSCode it doesn't:

[image]

The command line sticks to green after the program exits.